# Best practice for ERD that has more than 150+ columns

Tags: database, database-design, erd

What is the best practice to create an Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) that has more than 150 columns ? I need to create a documentation for my database, but at the moment I have a table that has more 150 columns, and all of these columns is required for the operationalization.

Comment: It's hard to say with no information. but I doubt that one entity has 150+ columns that rely on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key.  [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Well, I've seen such (normalized) tables. If you want a readable ERD, then omit columns using ellipses, e.g. "supplier : supplier_id, name, country_id, ...". In my opinion an ERD should contain only the most important columns anyway. It is made to get a look at relations. If you plaster it with columns, it becomes large and thus too hard to read - especially with many tables.